# Proving $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} x^2 = 1$ by definition, without using $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Prove by definition that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} x^2 = 1$$

My proof, (without using $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$; **we must not use that**):

$$|x^2 - 1| < \epsilon $$

**If $x^2 - 1 < 0$ then:**
$$\begin{align}
-(x^2 - 1) < \epsilon &\iff -x^2 < \epsilon - 1 \\
&\iff x^2 > -\epsilon + 1 \\
&\iff -\sqrt{-\epsilon + 1} < x < \sqrt{-\epsilon + 1} \\
&\implies |x|<\sqrt{-\epsilon+1} \\
&\iff |x+1| < \sqrt{-\epsilon+1}+1 \leq\delta
\end{align}$$

**If $x^2 - 1 \geq 0$ then:**
$$\begin{align}
x^2 - 1<\epsilon &\iff x^2 < \epsilon + 1 \\
&\iff -\sqrt{\epsilon + 1} < x < \sqrt{\epsilon + 1} \\
&\implies |x| < \sqrt{\epsilon+1} \\
&\iff |x|+1<\sqrt{\epsilon+1}+1 \\
&\iff |x+1|<\sqrt{\epsilon+1}+1 \\
&\implies \sqrt{\epsilon + 1}+1 \leq \delta
\end{align}$$

How to complete it to the end? Can I just say that $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon+1}+1$? Why do we sometimes say $\delta := \min{\{1, \sqrt{1+\epsilon}+1\}}$ or other value in the second argument?

Is there any mistake?

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} = x^2$ mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It was a typo, I corrected it

Comment: Your first case has an algebra error, you did not multiply the minus sign out correctly.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I corrected it

Comment: $|x^2 - 1| < \epsilon \implies -\epsilon < x^2-1 < \epsilon$

Comment: There is still an error in your work, it has moved to the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that $|x^2 - 1| < \epsilon$:
 $ |x^2 - 1|=|(x-1)^2+2(x-1)| \le |x-1|^2 +2|x-1| < \epsilon\implies |x-1|^2 +2|x-1| - \epsilon <0 \implies$
$0 \le |x-1| < \sqrt{1+\epsilon} -1 $ (using quadratic formula). Thus, it's sufficient to pick $\delta=\sqrt{1+\epsilon} -1$

Comment: My teacher sometimes does something like this $\delta = \min\{1 , \text{another value}\}$

Can I ask you why does he use value $1$ everytime and why the minimum function

Comment: @BiliDebili: sometimes you need to select $\delta$ to satisfy multiple conditions (i.e. look up proofs for limit of sum or product), In that case, minimum value needs to be picked. Value of $1$ is probably just a coincidence, it does not have to be one all the time.